# Generate script SQL to insert comment on tables and columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle 12 database with a schema with 50+ tables and 500+ columns without comments/documentation. I need to generate documentation for the whole schema and I've to comment all tables and columns. Is there an easy way to generate an SQL script pre-compiled with all statements, for example:

```
comment on table EMPLOYE IS '';
comment on column EMPLOYE.EMPLOYE_ID IS '';
```

Or, I'm unlucky and I need to create every single entry myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the table from the Oracle data dictionary and build a simple script. E.g., for comments on the table...

```
 select 'comment on table  ' || table_anme  || ' is ' ||  ''
 from   dba_tables
 where  owner='schema_name'
```

and use the proper table (i.e., `DBA_TAB_COLS`) for columns too.